# Direct limits and prufer group

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I need some help with this exercise in module theory:

(1) Consider the directed partial ordered set $(\mathbb{N},\leq)$ and the direct system with modules $M_n=\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ and morphisms defined by:
\begin{equation}
\mu_{n,n+1}:\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/p^{n+1}\mathbb{Z}
\end{equation}
such that:
\begin{equation}
a+p^n\mathbb{Z}\mapsto pa+p^{n+1}\mathbb{Z}
\end{equation}
Show that:
\begin{equation}
\lim_\longrightarrow M_n=\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)
\end{equation}

(2) Same settings as in the previous point except for the map $\mu_{n,n+1}$ that is defined as:
\begin{equation}
a+p^n\mathbb{Z}\mapsto p^2a+p^{n+1}\mathbb{Z}
\end{equation}
Show that:
\begin{equation}
\lim_\longrightarrow M_n=0
\end{equation}

SOLUTION

I know that since the partial ordered set $(\mathbb{N},\leq)$ is directed and then I know that the direct limit $\displaystyle {M=\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty \mu_n(M_n)}$ with $\mu_n:M_n\to M$ such that $\mu_{n+1}\circ\mu_{n,n+1}=\mu_n$.

I also know that the direct limit is isomporphic to the set:
\begin{equation}
M\simeq\bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty M_n/S
\end{equation}
with $S$ the submodule generated by elements of the form $\mu_{n,n+1}(x_n)-x_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}, x_n\in M_n$.

Now substituting the hypothesis of the exercise we have that $S$ is generated by elements of the form:
\begin{equation}
\mu_{n,n+1}(x_n)-x_n=pa+p^{n+1}\mathbb{Z}-(a+p^n\mathbb{Z})
\end{equation}

Now I'm not able to continue, can someone help?

Comment: what're you stuck on?

Comment: Proving that the first direct limit is isomorphic to the prufer group and that the second is 0

Comment: For 2), as a hint, what happens if you repeatedly apply the maps to any point of $M_n$?

Comment: which maps do you mean?

Comment: @Pefok I didn't ask you to repeat your question, I asked where you got stuck on while answering it.

Comment: Sorry, I got stuck on the last thing that I’ve written in the solution because I really don’t know how to show that the direct sum modulo S is equal to the prufer group

Comment: Do you know the universal property of direct sum? You can prove this just by checking easily that the prufer group or 0 satisfies the universal property.

Comment: @Erica yes, can you explain me more in detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can verify that these two groups satisfy the universal property.
Here I give the proof of (1) as an example.

We have a family of homomorphisms $f_{n}:M_{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}(p^{\infty})\simeq \mathbb{Z}[1/p]/\mathbb{Z}, 1\operatorname{mod}p^{n}\mapsto 1/p^{n}\operatorname{mod}\mathbb{Z}$.
These homomorphisms satisfy $f_{n+1}\circ \mu_{n,n+1}=f_{n}$.

For any abelian group $G$ with a family of homomorphisms $g_{n}:M_{n}\rightarrow G$ such that $g_{n+1}\circ \mu_{n,n+1}=g_{n}$.
Denote by $a_{n}$ the image of $1\operatorname{mod} p^{n}$ under $g_{n}$,
and we have $a_{n}=pa_{n+1}$.
Hence we can define a homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}(p^{\infty})$ to $G$:
$$\Phi:\mathbb{Z}(p^{\infty})\rightarrow G, 1/p^{n}\operatorname{mod} \mathbb{Z} \mapsto a_{n},$$
which is obviously well-defined and is the unique one satisfying $\Phi\circ f_{n}=g_{n}$ for each $n$.
This shows that $\mathbb{Z}(p^{\infty})$ is isomorphic to the direct limit of $(M_{n},\mu_{n,n+1}).$